# IE9 strange behavior

Tags: wordpress, class, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

if you browse http://www.new-way.it/qualias site with ie9, appear a strange code line in the footer near social networks box:

what is?!

Another strange behavior in the Page with ie9:

http://www.new-way.it/qualias/?page_id=166

can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- it is expected that questions here relate to a specific programming problem. Posting a link to your site and asking others to visit and debug your issue is frowned upon, mostly because once the issue is fixed, the evidence simply disappears. You should post the line of code here and indicate what you've tried to eliminate or identify it.

Answer (score 0):

The code is being added via Javascript, it's a class called ie7_anon ie7_class19 and it has what should be inline CSS added as text -> none !important.

So why is some IE7 related stuff being shown? Your markup has forced IE9 into quirks mode so I'd start by removing your validation errors. That might be the cause.  However you also have some css and js being applied to all IE versions here;

```
        <!--[if IE]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.new-way.it/qualias/wp-content/themes/custom-community/styleIE.css" />
             <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.new-way.it/qualias/wp-content/themes/custom-community/js/ie7-standard-p.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
```

There's some problem with that too that needs fixed (the fact it's outputting CSS to text).

Comment: your solution fix the footer case, but the page http://www.new-way.it/qualias/?page_id=166 has yet strange behavior ...